# Sort dictionary by value then append the sorted values to a text file

Tags: python, sorting, file-io, dictionary, operator-keyword

I took a very short course at university and now my labs I'm working in want to me write a small program and its completely above me.

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   2
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  3
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 2 etc...
```

With the letters being the key and numbers value.
I used this code to compare it to a list to pull out specific keys.

```
x2 =  dict((option, d[option]) for option in x if option in d)
```

Which works fine.

Then i used this to sort it by value.

```
sorted_x2 = sorted(x2.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Which only works to sort it by the very first integer of the key, so the ordering goes like this

```
1,1,1 1, 13, 15, 2, 21, 24, 3, etc.. which is not useful
```

I don't know how to change this. I also then need to write the sorted_x2 to file preferably each on a separate line. But i have no idea how to process the sorted_x2 thing.

Comment: add `x2 ` and the output you expect

Answer (score 1):

Say you have your dictionary

```
d = {'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA':1,
     'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA':2, 
     'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA':3, 
     'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA':2}
```

You could use the following expression

```
l = sorted([(k, d[k]) for k in d], key = lambda i: i[1])
```

This will produce a `list` of `tuple`, sorted by value from your dictionary.

```
[('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 1),
 ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 2),
 ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 2),
 ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 3)]
```

Then to write to file

```
import csv
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    csvF = csv.writer(f)
    csvF.writerows(l)
```

Comment: The key must exist.... I'm iterating over the keys. Did I misunderstand OP's question? Where else are the keys coming from?

Comment: Hi, thanks but still gives me this

('AGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGCAT', '1'), ('CAGTGCGATGATGAAAGGGCAT', '1'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGCTT', '1'), ('AGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGCATA', '1'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAAGGCA', '1'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGCATA', '13'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGC', '15'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAGGG', '2'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGCAC', '2'), ('CAGTGCAATGTTGAAAGGGCA', '2'), ('CAGTGCAATGATAAAAGGGCA', '2'), ('CAGTGCAATGATAAAAGGGC', '2'), ('CAGTGCAATGTTGAAAGGGCAT', '2'), ('CAGTGCAATGATGAAAGGGCATT', '35')

so you see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting by the key **not** the value with `itemgetter(0)`, you need `itemgetter(1)` :

```
d = {"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" :1,
  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" :2,
  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" :3,
  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA":2,
  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA":22 }



sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

[('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 1), ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 2), ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 2), ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 3), ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 22)]

with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    for line in srtd:
         f.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Comment: Hi, sorry late responses, i thought i would get an email if someone replied to post. 

I tried this but i still get original problem of sorting by first integer only.

Comment: @pancakefacecake, theo code sorts by the values, I don't see how it does not work, add part of your actual dict

Comment: Hi, i converted the dict values into floats from string. Now it works perfectly. now to conquer writing to csv, cheeeers